# MySQL Fulltext in Binary Mode doesn't match phrases

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, phrase

Implementing a simple fulltext search I encountered a problem with the combination of **boolean mode** and **phrases**. Also worth noting is that the column has a **binary** collation (utf8_bin) whilst the table does not have this.

Given the following setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `test_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text_bin` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `text_bin` (`text_bin`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test` (`test_id`, `text_bin`) VALUES
(1, 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.'),
(2, 'Consectetuer Adipiscing Elit.'),
(3, 'Amet Sit Dolor Ipsum Lorem.')
;
```

Then running this query:

```
SELECT t.test_id, t.text_bin,
  MATCH(t.text_bin) AGAINST ('Lorem Ipsum' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as m_Words,
  MATCH(t.text_bin) AGAINST ('"Lorem Ipsum"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as m_Phrase,
  MATCH(t.text_bin) AGAINST ('Lorem' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as m_Lorem,
  MATCH(t.text_bin) AGAINST ('Ipsum' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as m_Ipsum
FROM test t
;
```

This yields the following results:

| test_id | text_bin | m_Words | m_Phrase | m_Lorem | m_Ipsum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet. | 0.0620 | 0 | 0.0310 | 0.0310 |
| 2 | Consectetuer Adipiscing Elit. | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | Amet Sit Dolor Ipsum Lorem. | 0.0620 | 0 | 0.0310 | 0.0310 |

(Note: I shortened the numbers to 4 decimal places for better readability.)

For the column `m_Phrase` I would expect a value greater then 0 on the first row. Is this a bug or can someone explain why the result is 0?

DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8qxR3SiPVtESU3saebhgBG/0

Comment: Yeah, I would definitely expect >0 value there. In fact, that should be the highest value as the phrase is found in 1 out of 3 row, not in 2 out of 3.

Answer (score 0):

My gut instinct is that this is to do with `space` delimiter.
The same happens with `utf8_unicode_ci`

Eg in this fiddle different collations give different results with both case sensitivity and matching of spaces as part of literals - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pi78uuA1RCFeToaRH9skcK/2

Update - Fiddle above updated with special chars (`.#*`), which match phrases as expected.

I don't know the solution to your problem other than use a different collation - just use `utf8_general_ci`

It would be interesting to know your use case or even the performance considerations that you face that (assumably) prompt you to use `utf8_bin`.

---

Update 2:

This looks like a reported [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92142). Although, from 2018... One fix appears to be to downgrade to version `5.7.19`.

It doesn't appear as though there is a working latest version approach for both a FULLTEXT based query with literal phrases and case sensitivity. Very very strange. The simplest (not perfect) approach would be the prepend each word with a plus, `+Lorem +Ipsum`, but would obviously lead to some false positives. (See above fiddle with `m_all` and `m_AllLower` fields.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using `utf8_bin` so that the search is **case sensitive**.

Comment: @jor - What version are you running?

Comment: @RickJames - MySQL 5.7.38

Answer (score 0):

Still failing in 8.0.31.

This might be a workaround:

```
WHERE MATCH(t.text_bin) AGAINST ('+Lorem +Ipsum' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND t.text_bin LIKE '%Lorem Ipsum%'
```

That is, avoid the phrase test in FT and use LIKE as a secondary filter to check for the phrase.

Alas, it won't let you display the relevance.

Comment: Yes, falling back to a `LIKE` condition is a workaround. For more complex phrases (i.e. wildcard) you can even use `REGEXP`. Only downside is missing relevance score and bad performance on a large text corpus.